# Open a pdf in new windows in IE9 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I used this code

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('../../files/registration/2013CRNNS_GuideforLicenceRenewalApplication.pdf','1','width=750,height=900')" >
```

to open a pdf in a new window which works fine in chrome, but when I tried it in IE9, the pdf file still opened, but the parent window became blank with only a `[object]` on it.

edit:
I just found out even I tried to open a html page instead of a pdf, it still happened

Comment: Have you had a look at this thread: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4191334

Comment: i just tried to open a html, it still happened, so maybe it is not the problem of pdf?

Comment: have you tried using a name for the window that doesn't start with a number? (in your example it is "1", try something like "window1").

Comment: @jackJoe, I tried without a name like "". it didn't work. So I tried another direction. here is my code： <a onclick="window.open('XXX.aspx','','width=500,height=600'); return false;" href="">. "return false" will avoid the parent page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the browser replaces the current document with whatever the expression `javascript:...` evaluates to. In this case, the returned value is an object representing the opened window, which becomes `[object Object]` (or something similar) when displayed as text. In order to avoid that, you should always use the `void` operator, which just discards its operand (technically, the `void` operator evaluates its operand, and returns `undefined`) :

```
<a href="javascript:void window.open(....)">
```

Comment: or maybe set href="#" to avoid it?

Comment: Just recall that href="#" means "go to the top of the page" by default. So, if you use onclick, you have to cancel the default behaviour anyway, with "return false" instead of "void".